# How to pass model from view to controlLer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i pass full model like by BeginForm etc... from view to contoller

```
    @model Business.Models.MyModel
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "User", FormMethod.Post)) //new {model = this.Model} NULL too
    { 
         <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(MyModel model)
    {
        TODO: now is null
    }
```

because now is always null

Model:

```
    public  IEnumerable<ReportInfo> Rank { get; set; }

    public Int32 SiteId
    {
        get { return UserUtils.CurrentSiteID; }
        set { UserUtils.CurrentSiteID = value; }
    }

    public Int32 PageSize { get; set; }

    public Int32 PageCount { get; set; }

    public Boolean UsePaging { get; set; }

    public Int32 CurrentPageNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    public String Sort { get; set; }

    public String Order { get; set; }

    public String SeachedWord { get; set; }

    public String JSON { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Sites { get; set; }

    /*Scrip method*/
```

Need to pass two IEnum fiels and couple simple fields without render. I know about Hidden fields BUT: when i'm getting rank and pass IEnum. I'm always getting exception `System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005)` about dangerous context

Comment: You need to render controls (`input`, `textarea`, `select`) for you model properties. Adding the existing model to the route parameters would be a bit pointless - `@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "User", Model, FormMethod.Post))` -  and it would fail if you model contained complex properties or collections anyway

Comment: I'm realy need to work with all model properties and when i'm trying to do some like this `@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "User", Model, FormMethod.Post))`,   i'm getting Potential dangerous Exeption `System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005):` - may be that because model it's too complex and huge, have IEnum's etc.

Comment: Could you post the code of your model?

Comment: No doubt - that's why i indicated it would be pointless and probably fail anyway (and what would be the point of sending the model to the view and posting it back completely unchanged!). You need to render controls for your properties - e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)`. Then the edited values will be bound to your model when you post back

Comment: Based on your edit, I assume you mean you want to post back some of the properties but not display them, in which case use `@Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.SomeProperty)` to render a hidden input. But it's better to use a view model to represent only what you want to display/edit.

Comment: I know about hidden fields - but I thought may be MVC have a some way to pass full model. Because this view have a two operation with this model first -this is a display - and more copmlicate it's an Export data

Comment: If this view is for display, why on earth would you have a `form`?

Answer (score 0):

For complex model, you should do as Stephen said. For simple model you can use EditorForModel. It'll render all the necessary fields of the model.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "User", FormMethod.Post))
    { 
     @Html.EditorForModel()
    }
```